# Qual a vantagem de usar o método Set<>?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Qual a vantagem ou diferença em utilizar o método `Set<>` sendo que eu posso fazer a mesma coisa sem ele como na alternativa 2?

#### Alternativa 1

```
var aluno = contexto.Alunos.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
contexto.Set<**Aluno**>().Remove(aluno);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

#### Alternativa 2

```
var aluno = contexto.Alunos.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
contexto.Alunos.Remove(aluno);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A escolha entre utilizar o método [DbContext.Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg679544%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) ou o objeto [DbSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instanciado no Contexto depende da utilização e de como você trabalha com o contexto.

O método `DbContext.Set<T>` retorna utilizando Generics o DbSet do contexto, avaliando o parâmetro de tipo da assinatura do método. Isso demonstra que quando chamamos o mesmo, ele realiza uma "pesquisa" nos objetos do contexto e "carrega" os dados daquele tipo dentro do Contexto.

O objeto `DbSet<T>` do Contexto é um objeto que em tese é carregado quando você instância o Contexto e este objeto é pré carregado para a utilização dentro da aplicação.

Os dois métodos realizam praticamente a mesma coisa, porém em momentos diferentes. Outro fator que pode influenciar na utilização de um ou de outro é a exposição dos objetos entre bibliotecas e namespaces diferentes. Se você repassar o seu contexto para um método utilizando a classe DbContext no enunciado deste método, você não tem conhecimento dos DbSets do contexto, portanto a forma de carregar os dados é utilizando o DbSet genérico. Abaixo um pequeno exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }

    public Contexto()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Aluno
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{    
    public List<Aluno> GetAlunos(DbContext ctx)
    {
        // O compilador não irá reconhecer se chamarmos o DbSet ctx.Alunos.
        return ctx.Set<Aluno>().ToList();
    }

    public List<Aluno> GetAlunos2(Contexto ctx)
    {
        return ctx.Alunos.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A vantagem na verdade existe quando você quer implementar um comportamento genérico em alguma função sua.

Por exemplo, você quer escrever um método que traga apenas os 10 primeiros registros de qualquer `DbSet`. Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public IEnumerable<T> PrimeirosDez<T>() {
    return contexto.Set<T>().Take(10).ToList();
}
```

Ou seja, implemento uma extensão para o contexto que traz os 10 primeiros elementos para qualquer `DbSet`.

Uso:

```
var teste = PrimeirosDez<Aluno>();
var teste2 = PrimeirosDez<Professor>();
```

Comment: Cigado, mas o T não foi definido com um tipo específico para ser usado? Como no exemplo que você deu, T espera um classe podendo ser Aluno ou Professor?

Comment: Você pode limitar `T` usando uma sintaxe assim: `public IEnumerable<T> PrimeirosDez<T>() where T: class, IMinhaInterface { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

Neste caso específico realmente não há vantagem. Use a segunda forma.

Este método foi criado para situação onde você não sabe com que tipo de dado está trabalhando, ou seja, quando está escrevendo código genérico:

```
contexto.Set<T>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/Set.cs).

Eu sei que tem alguma vantagem quando se está usando *migrations* mas não conheço em profundidade.

Comment: bigown, mas com genérico eu não especifico um tipo determinado, diferente de collections?

Comment: Então, quando você está escrevendo um código genérico você vai usar um "tipo variável", ou seja, o `T`. Depois quando for usar estes código que você escreveu aí você vai passar o tipo que está usando para ser substituído em `T`. Mas aí você não estará usando o tipo (no seu exemplo `Aluno`) no `Set<>` e sim no seu código. Ou seja, o `Set<>` serve só para produzir código genéricos e não para consumir códigos genéricos. Se você sabe que vai usar sempre `Aluno` não produza um código genérico. Está criando um código genérico?Acho que não.Então use o `contexto.Alunos.Remove(aluno)` e não se preocupe